# NetBeans installer closes on a white screen after "Configuring the installer..."

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

I'm having some trouble installing apache netbeans 11.2, (and in general any version of netbeans) on my pc because when I run the installer the error, described in the title happens.

- There are no lock files.
- I have jdk 13.0.1 installed,  (and  java 8u231)
- I'm running it as administrator

(Update) Since there is a 30000 character limit I've replaced the log with the NetBeans\11.2\var\log\messages.txt and removed the Turning on modules: ...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Monday, December 2, 2019 at 12:11:03 PM Central European Standard Time
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2
  Operating System        = Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 13.0.1; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 13.0.1+9; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 13.0.1+9
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1
  System Locale; Encoding = hu_HU (nb); Cp1250
  Home Directory          = C:\Users\banhi
  Current Directory       = C:\netbeans\bin
  User Directory          = C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.2
  Cache Directory         = C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.2
  Installation            = C:\netbeans\nb
                            C:\netbeans\ergonomics
                            C:\netbeans\ide
                            C:\netbeans\extide
                            C:\netbeans\java
                            C:\netbeans\apisupport
                            C:\netbeans\webcommon
                            C:\netbeans\websvccommon
                            C:\netbeans\enterprise
                            C:\netbeans\profiler
                            C:\netbeans\php
                            C:\netbeans\harness
                            C:\netbeans\groovy
                            C:\netbeans\javafx
                            C:\netbeans\platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = 
  Application Classpath   = C:\netbeans\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util-ui.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\netbeans\platform\core\asm-all-5.0.1.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\core\core-base.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\core\core.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\core\org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar;C:\netbeans\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\netbeans\nb\core\org-netbeans-upgrader.jar;C:\netbeans\nb\core\locale\core_nb.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: The extension C:\netbeans\ide\modules\ext\jcodings-1.0.18.jar may be multiply loaded by modules: [C:\netbeans\ide\modules\org-netbeans-libs-bytelist.jar, C:\netbeans\ide\modules\org-netbeans-modules-textmate-lexer.jar]; see: http://www.netbeans.org/download/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/classpath.html#class-path
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/C:/netbeans/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.lib, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ant.hints, org.netbeans.modules.java.hints, org.netbeans.modules.jshell.support, org.netbeans.modules.maven.hints] use org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.legacy.spi which is deprecated: Use Java Hints SPI (org.netbeans.spi.java.hints) instead.
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageLockJsonDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-NpmDebugLogDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageLockJsonDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageJsonDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-NpmDebugLogDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageJsonDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageLockJsonDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-NpmDebugLogDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageLockJsonDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageJsonDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-NpmDebugLogDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageJsonDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-NpmDebugLogDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageLockJsonDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 127 for both Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageJsonDataObject-Registration.xml and Services/MIMEResolver/org-netbeans-modules-javascript-nodejs-file-PackageLockJsonDataObject-Registration.xml
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.eclipselink/modules/ext/docs/javax.persistence-2.1.0-doc.zip
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.eclipselink/modules/ext/eclipselink/eclipselink.jar
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.libs.javacapi/modules/ext/nb-javac-api.jar
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.libs.jaxb/modules/ext/jaxb/jaxb-impl.jar
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.libs.jaxb/modules/ext/jaxb/jaxb-xjc.jar
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api/modules/ext/jaxb/api/jsr173_1.0_api.jar
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.libs.jaxb/modules/ext/jaxb/jaxb-impl.jar
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.libs.jaxb/modules/ext/jaxb/jaxb-xjc.jar
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api/modules/ext/jaxb/api/jsr173_1.0_api.jar
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.libraries.J2SELibraryTypeProvider]: Can not resolve URL: nbinst://org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.eclipselink/modules/ext/docs/javax.persistence-2.1.0-doc.zip
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.

//Had to remove turning on modules... due to 30000 character limit

INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown.core@2.6.0.v20150901-2143 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.core@2.6.0.v20150901-2143 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.jgit.java7@3.6.2.201501210735-r resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.core@2.6.0.v20150901-2143 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle net.java.html.sound@1.6.1 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle net.java.html.boot.script@1.6.1 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle net.java.html.geo@1.6.1 resolved
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 started
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Windows
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.windows.WindowsNetworkProxy]: Windows system proxy resolver: auto detect
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: fell to default (correct if direct mode went before)
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.home has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.platformdefinition.Util.removeNBArtifacts(Util.java:337)
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    -Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
    -Xss2m
    -Djdk.gtk.version=2.2
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
    -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
    -Dplugin.manager.check.updates=false
    -Dnetbeans.extbrowser.manual_chrome_plugin_install=yes
    --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing.text=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/javax.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.event=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-opens=jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-modules=jdk.jshell
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.annotation=ALL-UNNAMED
    --add-exports=jdk.javadoc/com.sun.tools.javadoc.main=ALL-UNNAMED
    -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
    -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\netbeans\platform
    -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.2
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.2\var\log\heapdump.hprof
    -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\netbeans\nb;C:\netbeans\ergonomics;C:\netbeans\ide;C:\netbeans\extide;C:\netbeans\java;C:\netbeans\apisupport;C:\netbeans\webcommon;C:\netbeans\websvccommon;C:\netbeans\enterprise;C:\netbeans\mobility;C:\netbeans\profiler;C:\netbeans\python;C:\netbeans\php;C:\netbeans\identity;C:\netbeans\harness;C:\netbeans\cnd;C:\netbeans\cndext;C:\netbeans\dlight;C:\netbeans\groovy;C:\netbeans\extra;C:\netbeans\javacard;C:\netbeans\javafx
    exit
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 256,0MB maximum 4082,0MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 7,3MB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: G1 Young Generation (Collections=21 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: G1 Old Generation (Collections=0 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=11437 total loaded=11442 unloaded 5
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 17 114 759 168
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 16 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 32 binary roots took: 334 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\banhi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NASAInSight\src took: 280 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\banhi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\src took: 46 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\banhi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NASAInSight\test took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\banhi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test\test took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 4 source roots took: 326 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 1 ms]
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common.project.ActionProviderSupport.verifyUserPropertiesFile(ActionProviderSupport.java:927)
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.XMLDataObject@66d7a096[MultiFileObject@286f4280[Actions/Help/master-help.xml]]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@b4648e[MultiFileObject@2acdee67[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 15 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 1 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\netbeans\webcommon\jsstubs\reststubs.zip took: 98 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\netbeans\webcommon\jsstubs\corestubs.zip took: 46 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\netbeans\webcommon\jsstubs\domstubs.zip took: 49 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 3 source roots took: 193 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.mercurial]: version: null
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.subversion]: Finished indexing svn cache with 0 entries. Elapsed time: 0 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 48 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 20 binary roots took: 2 938 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Users\banhi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NASAInSight\src took: 385 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 1 source roots took: 385 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]

INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 256
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.progress.spi.InternalHandle]: Cannot switch to silent mode when not running at org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.MenuWarmUpTask$NbWindowsAdapter$1HandleBridge.run(MenuWarmUpTask.java:244)
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.9.1.v20140110-1610 stopped
INFO [null]: Last record repeated again.
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.progress.spi.InternalHandle]: Cannot switch to silent mode when not running at org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.MenuWarmUpTask$NbWindowsAdapter$1HandleBridge.run(MenuWarmUpTask.java:244)
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated more than 10 times, further logs of this record are ignored until the log record changes.
```

Comment: Maybe: **`Reboot`**, temporarily disable **`anti-virus`**, then try to install? You can also try **`logging in as a different user`** and try to install (also disabling security software in the process). Check for **`disk errors`**, **`full disk`**, **`malware`**, **`runtime versions & overall presence`**, etc... [**Short check list**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49987350/129130), [**long check list**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431725/the-setup-process-in-windows-fails-access-denied-when-trying-to-create-uc-micro/48433935#48433935). Virtual to install on if you are in a hurry?

Comment: [1] Strange, since from the log messages it looks like everything went OK. [2] Are there any errors in the NetBeans log file? In your case that file is probably named `C:\Users\banhi\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.2\var\log\messages.log`. [3] It doesn't resolve your problem at all, but as a workaround (which works fine for me) you could just download the zip of NetBeans 11.2, unzip it into some directory, and then open `..../bin/netbeans64.exe`. The [link for the zip download is on this page](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html) after the text _"Binaries:"_.

Comment: Thank you, the portable version works, I've replaced the log with the messages.txt

Comment: [1] What you have shown is the NetBeans log file for your NetBeans **8.2** installation. Instead, you need to show the log file (if it exists) for your NetBeans **11.2** installation. That will reside in a directory named **...\NetBeans\11.2\var\log** (not **...\NetBeans\8.2\var\log**) as mentioned in my previous comment. [2] Depending on how far your failed installation progressed, that log file may or may not exist, but if it does please update your question. [3] However, based on your most recent comment, isn't your installation of NetBeans 11.2 working now?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I've updated it with the correct one. Yes I'm using a portable version temporarly, but I've noticed, that weirdly other IDEs like visual studio installer wont work either. Not sure if it has something to do with this, but all that does is preparing... then closes.

Comment: @LeventeBanhidy OK. I've no further ideas, though it seems odd that VS installer is giving you problems as well. Perhaps check your machine environment to see if you are hitting some limit (space on C: drive, RAM, etc..).