# Unable to install Microchip Studio due to Windows Task Manager for Microchip Studio installer

Tags: windows-installer

[image]

While downloading Microchip Studio, I faced this error message.

Is there anyone who happens to know the solution? Thank you.

Comment: If you are running the web-installer - perhaps try to download the offline version (full installer) and try to run that from your local disk or network.

Answer (score 1):

***Local Installation Media (UPDATE )***: Please try to download the full installation media (as opposed to running the web-version) and try to launch that again after rebooting. [See section 17 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130). Though obvious, if your installer still fails, please try it on another computer too (or virtual). Make sure to install with full admin rights and with any anti virus software behaving itself (disable if possible).

---

***Windows Update***: Generally one would have to have a look at [the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890) to know exactly what this is. The main  [**recommended read on logging**](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407) shows you how to look for both **MSI and Burn setup.exe log files** (several logs).

However, at face value it looks like Windows Update is running and you should let it complete and then reboot your computer and try again. Keep in mind that Windows Update could start again after reboot.  Though you can stop it, I would let it finish and reboot again. `Perhaps some of those driver setups (see image below) could trigger something from Windows Update?` Again: hard to say without checking logs.

***Virtual Machine?***: Is this a virtual machine? They tend to have this problem as they are reverted to a prior state and then Windows Update starts all the time when you need the virtual.

> ***In short***: let Windows Update finish and reboot. Disable any anti virus that might block your setup. And while you wait for Windows
> Update, try on another computer? (to verify that the setup is OK).

---

***UPDATE***: Extract files from **`setup.exe`** (how-to: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52338626/129130), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51941558/129130)). If you have the [WiX 3.11 toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/wix3/) installed you can extract all files from the **`as-installer-7.0.2594-full.exe`** as follows (**`out`** is the folder where files are extracted to).

```
"%WIX%bin\dark.exe" -x out as-installer-7.0.2594-full.exe
```

There are a lot of MSI files and other files here (the below image shows just a few of them). A complex setup - that is all I know about the product. Any one of these installers could trigger the problem described - check the log files (also the event viewer logs):

[image: Setup list extract]

---

***Check Lists***: Below are some links to setup.exe check lists. Common problems and some suggestions for how to deal with them.

- [A list of common installer issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130)
- [A chattier version of installer issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433935/129130)

---

***Links:***

- [Extensive collection of links on WiX and setup issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)
- Packaging notes: https://www.itninja.com/software/microchip-technology/atmel-studio/7-2502

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and nothing worked. Then I realised that I wasn't the User wasn't an Admin ... so I reran the installer as an Admin and the problem went away. Perhaps this might solve your issue as well.