# Service not being installed properly using WIX installer

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

As the title says, I am have the following snippet of a code that installs a service using wix

```
<Directory Id="Test" Name="Test">
        <Component Id="ConnectorMainService" Guid="{SOME-ID}">
          <CreateFolder/>
          <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Name="$(var.PRODUCT_NAME)" DisplayName="$(var.PRODUCT_NAME)" Description="$(var.DESCRIPTION)" Start="auto" Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no" Vital="yes"/>
              <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="$(var.PRODUCT_NAME)" Wait="yes"/>
        </Component>
</Directory>
```

I had to put a <CreateFolder> in there, otherwise I have the same issues as described in this question ([Why does my WiX installer need an empty CreateFolder to conditionally update an Xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241056/why-does-my-wix-installer-need-an-empty-createfolder-to-conditionally-update-an)).

The difference I have is even having the <CreateFolder> there, the installer exits without creating the service, it just creates the Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `CreateFolder` element with a `File` element for the service executable itself. The Windows Installer requires the service's executable `File` and `ServiceInstall` elements to be in the same `Component` (specifically, the service executable must be the `KeyPath` of the `Component` but WiX will take care of that for you if you put the executable `File` element first in the `Component`).